# Understanding pattern rules

Tags: makefile

I am trying to wrap my head around pattern rules and how they function. I am using [this](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/1.18/t_pattern.html) article for reference which states

> A pattern rule is a concise way of specifying a rule for many files at
>   once. The rule will depend on the file names, but usually it depends
>   on them in a simple way. You specify a pattern by using the %
>   wildcard. When present in the dependency list, % matches any string of
>   any length; when present in the list of targets, % stands for the
>   string that % in the dependency list matched.
>
> The following pattern rule will take any .c file and compile it into a
>   .o file:
>
> `%.o: %.c     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $(input) -o $(output)`
>
> (This assumes that you have the variables CC, CFLAGS, and INCLUDES
>   defined to be something suitable. Makepp will guess a value for CC and
>   CFLAGS.)
>
> The first line of the rule says that it applies to every possible
>   input file that matches the pattern %.c. These .c files can be
>   transformed into the corresponding .o file using the specified
>   actions.
>
> The action of rule is quite similar to the other actions we've seen
>   previously, except that it uses automatic variables. An automatic
>   variable is a variable whose value is automatically set by makepp
>   depending on the rule that it appears in. Some useful automatic
>   variables are:

```
$(input)
    The name of the first input file. In this rule, this would be the file that matches the %.c pattern. $(dependency) is a synonymn for $(input). In older makefiles, you will also see the cryptic symbol $< used as well. 
$(output)
    The name of the first output file. In this rule, this would be the file that matches the %.o pattern. $(target) and $@ are synonymns. 
$(inputs)
    The name of all explicitly listed input files. In this case, since there is only one, $(inputs) is equivalent to $(input). $(dependencies) and $^ are synonymns. 
$(outputs)
    The name of all explicitly listed targets. In this case, since there is only one, $(outputs) is equivalent to $(output). $(targets) is a synonymn for $(outputs).
```

Here are the questions that I have:

1 ) Suppose I have 2 files FileA.c and FileB.c. When I apply the above mentioned pattern rule how would that apply  to the above two files. The example given only deals with one file.

2) Whats the difference between the automatic variable `input` and `inputs`

Answer (score 0):

A pattern rule will be applied to **each** target file that matches the rule that make needs to build.

So if you need to build both `FileA.o` and `FileB.o` (because they are both listed as prerequisites of some other target (e.g. `FileBin: FileA.o FileB.o`) that rule will be run twice, once for each.

Take the rule

```
FileBin: FileA.o FileB.o
        @echo '$$input = $(input)'
        @echo '$$inputs = $(inputs)'
```

When run that would output

```
$input = FileA.o
$inputs = FileA.o FileB.o
```

It should also be pointed out that `input` and `output` are makepp variable names and not valid for GNU make itself.